# UEFI shell file system order

Tags: uefi

When I have a bootable USB drive inserted, my UEFI shell places that drive at the FS0 position. As a result, my hard drive, which has the startup.nsh on the boot partition (labeled efidir, not boot), is placed at fs4. The shell can't boot from the startup.nsh, because the efidir partition isn't mounted. When I don't have the USB drive in place, everything works (the hard drive is at FS0, startup.nsh runs, the system boots. To run the startup with a USB in place, I have to switch to FS4 and then run startup from the command line.

Is there a way for me to force the shell to place the hard drive at the FS0 location on the map, regardless of the existence of the USB drive?

Comment: On my system, startup.nsh is run whether it is on FS0 or FS4. Perhaps startup.nsh is being run, but it doesn’t work as expected because the script itself relies on the drive mappings. Try putting an echo as the first line of the script to see if it starts. You can change the script to work independently of which drive mapping it is on.

Comment: As written, the question is off-topic, but if the problem is actually within the script, then it would be on topic. You would need to add the script to the question.

Comment: Exactly right...Thank you. I fixed the script to look for the startup script and load the file system it is found on.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't understand the off-topic/on-topic comment. Given that I had no idea if the problem was within the script or not, how could the question be off-topic?